# Get the result of javascript function while scraping web page content

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, c#-4.0, html-parsing

Is it possible to extract the value of a variable used in java script in a web page. I need to get the url stored in javascript function in a web page. In web page the function is called using `<a href`,

when we click on that hyperlink , java script function is called and the url is returned.
Below is the code,

`<a class="dld" OnClick="download_file();" href="javascript:">&nbsp;</a>`

The script function is

```
function download_file() {
    var summaryFlag     = 0;
        if(document.getElementById("frmincludefile").checked){
    summaryFlag=1; }
    url = '/filedatabase/file_process_request.html?mru=53616c7465645f5f3f24b8f4a86301eb202e67fbb679df4356e24fee9d7a17a099010eb5acf5985c&type=doc';
    url += '&sum='+summaryFlag+'&logo=0&xcode=xtritiuminx&serve_txt=0&folderid=';
    document.location   = url;
}
```

How can i get value of url variable.

Comment: What do you mean "in a web page"? In code behind?

Comment: No, I'm extracting the content from a web page. I need to know how to extract the value of variable used in javascript.

Comment: Sounds like he is scraping a page he doesn't control.

Comment: Yes, Bert Evans. I'm scraping the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to the result of java script function but now i'm invoking the javascript using
`webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("download_file");`
By invoking the java script i'm able to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `URL` var value in any `hidden field`

for e.g.

```
document.getElementById("hidden_field_name").value = url;
```

Comment: I can't edit the function , since i'm extracting data from a web page. The url contains the path to download a file, how to extract that variable content.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using variable in the upper scope. In the example bellow I'm using global variable (bad practice) to save the `localUrl` value from the redirect function:

```
var url = '';

function redirect() {
  var googleRadio = document.getElementById('google');
  if (googleRadio.checked) {
    localUrl = 'http://google.com';
    url = localUrl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Minko Gechev. But i'm scraping the page, i can't write any functions in the page. How to get the value once the page load is completed.

Comment: If you are calling the download_file on mouse click you can get the value only on user interaction. You also can simulate it with firing the event (trigger of jQuery) but I don't think that the code will be very "beautiful" and readable in that case.